# setRequestProperty wiith parameters Content-Type and text/html;charset=iso-8859-1 does not work

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Ia am trying to get the content  of an an page with the following content type:

meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"

For this iam using the class HttpConnection like this

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=iso-8859-1");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
in.close();
```

In the Respionse are many "?" so i thin the text was not encoded withe the character set. what can id do to get the response encoded with charset iso-8859-1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The encoding is right. The InputstreamReader needs an second parameter, which is the encoding. then it works